# How do you assign n polynomials to n variables?

Tags: python, numpy

The title says it all. I'm supposed to do this assignement:

```py
def fit(x, y, deg):
    p1, p2, ..., pn = [numpy.poly1d(numpy.polyfit(x, y, i)) for i in deg]
```

Where `x`, `y` are `numpy.array` of equal length, `deg` is a `list` of length `n` containing real numbers. Don't bother to much with the expression in the `list`, it could just as well be `p1, p2, ... , pn = [i for i in deg]`. All i know is that `len(deg)` is `n`.

Update:

I will have the solution to my specific problem if someone can tell me why i get invalid syntax on this:

`for i in xrange(len(deg)):
    exec("y{:s} = {:s}".format(str(i), str(numpy.poly1d(numpy.polyfit(x, y, i + 1)))(x))`

`deg =  [1, 2, 3]`, `x and y` are `numpy.array` of equal length containing numbers.

Here is a general solution for assigning `n` variables to `n` objects within a `list` of length `n`:

`for i in xrange(len(list)):
    exec("variable_name{:s} = {}".format(str(i), list[i]))`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just keep the list?

Comment: how would you retrieve these variables after ?

Comment: I'm intend to keep the list yes. The variables are supposed to be iterated over the `x array` ; `p1(x), p2(x), ...., pn(x)` and later used for plotting.

Comment: then just do `p = [...]`. Later, you can access `p[0]`, `p[1]`, ...

Answer (score 2):

You can just create `p1,p2,...,pk,...` as members of the locals() dictionnary :

```
p=[numpy.poly1d(numpy.polyfit(x, y, i)) for i in deg]
for i in deg : locals()['p'+str(i)]=p[i]
```

But it's very tricky and can't be widely recommended.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to assign *names* to each item in the list, but you want those names to follow a numeric pattern. We give *names* to variables when it's easier for us human programmers to keep track by name. If we're using numbers

Explicitly-named variables work with two items:

```
letter0, letter1 = ['a', 'b']
assert letter0 == 'a'
assert letter1 == 'b'
```

Now you could add `letter2` and so on, but why go to the hassle of adding names for individual items when you don't even know how many there will be?

If you assign a name to the whole list, then you can use index notation `[]` (like the subscript in mathematical texts, if that's what you're used to):

```
letters = ['a', 'b']
assert letters[0] == 'a'
assert letters[1] == 'b'
```

Same result, but now it works no matter how many are there.

---

So if you keep the list, your code might look like this:

```
def fit(x, y, deg):
    ps = [numpy.poly1d(numpy.polyfit(x, y, i)) for i in deg]

    # You mentioned you wanted to use p1(x) or similar.
    # You can access each "p" by index:
    the_x_array_applied_to_the_first_p = p[0](x)
    the_x_array_applied_to_the_next_p = p[1](x)

    # You can do it over the whole list, too:
    the_x_array_applied_to_each_p = [p(x) for p in ps]
```